# How do I select one of two records by choosing the smaller value in another field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Attached is a sample of my data. Within my data I have two client IDs. This means they have a primary and secondary pay source ID(insurance). The primary insurance is dictated by the lower priority number. What I want to do is select only distinct client ID records and only primary pay source IDs for ones that appear twice(not all do). Below is the query I tried but it has not worked.

```
SELECT 
    CLIENT_ID, PAYSRC_ID,
    MIN([PRIORITY]) AS PRI,
    EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRES_DATE
FROM 
    CDCLINS
WHERE 
    EXPIRES_DATE IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    CLIENT_ID, PAYSRC_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRES_DATE
ORDER BY 
    CLIENT_ID
```

[image: Data_example]

Comment: "...but it has not worked." is not helpful to someone assisting in troubleshooting a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use an analytic to set a row number ordered by priority and then limit to that first row of each client_ID (partition)

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    CLIENT_ID
  , PAYSRC_ID
  , PRIORITY
  , EFFECTIVE_DATE
  , EXPIRES_DATE
  , row_number() over (partition by client_ID order by priority asc) rn
FROM CDCLINS
WHERE EXPIRES_DATE IS NULL
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID
```

You could also do this in a subquery as well and avoid the CTE.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
      CLIENT_ID
    , PAYSRC_ID
    , PRIORITY
    , EFFECTIVE_DATE
    , EXPIRES_DATE
    , row_number() over (partition by client_ID order by priority asc) rn
  FROM CDCLINS
  WHERE EXPIRES_DATE IS NULL) CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID
```

A third approach would be to generate a set of data that only consists of the CLIENT_ID and the lowest Priority and then JOIN this data set back to the base set allowing the inner join to limit the data to just the min priority for each client.  This approach is most common if the database doesn't support analytic functions.

```
SELECT 
    A.CLIENT_ID
  , PAYSRC_ID
  , PRIORITY
  , EFFECTIVE_DATE
  , EXPIRES_DATE
FROM CDCLINS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT CLIENT_ID, MIN(Priority) mPri 
            FROM CDCLINS
            GROUP BY Client_ID) B
  on A.CLIENT_ID = B.Client_ID
 and A.Priority = B.mPri
WHERE EXPIRES_DATE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular query :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    CLIENT_ID INT,
    PAYSRC_ID INT,
    PRIORITY INT
)
INSERT @T SELECT 3156,3200,1
INSERT @T SELECT 3156,9000,8
INSERT @T SELECT 3157,9000,8
INSERT a@T SELECT 3157,300,1
INSERT @T SELECT 3159,3200,1
INSERT @T SELECT 3154,9000,8


SELECT
    CLIENT_ID,
    PAYSRC_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CLIENT_ID,
        PAYSRC_ID,
        ReverseRowNumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY PRIORITY ASC)
    FROM
        @T
) AS X 
WHERE
    ReverseRowNumber=1
```